# Is my PC ruined?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I just ran the command `del *.*.* --force` to remove a virtualbox disk image, but CMD printed out a bunch of "Access is denied" errors. Is my PC hosed, or is it still in working condition? I was running CMD in admin mode

Comment: the asterisks are spaced because otherwise superuser treats it as formatting.

Comment: use backticks. Feel free to fix the command if its wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends in which directory you used the command and with what rights.
Perhaps try restarting your computer and see if some problems are showing up or some files are missing.

Comment: I used the command in the `C:\Users\<user-name>\VirtualBox VMs` folders and command prompt was in administrator mode.

Comment: None system critical files should have been deleted. Only files with 2 dots (`*.*.*`) in the filename.